# Blogger: How to create a dropdown of posts by category/label

Tags: json, blogs, blogger

Hi I have a Food blog and I have created multiple labels like "Appetizers", "Deserts" etc..

I have successfully created dropdowns of posts, one for each label. But I want to display the category/label name as the default text in the dropdown instead of "Select a Post.

For eg: A dropdown of Appetizers will have default text in the dropdown as "Appetizers" and NOT "Select a Post", followed by the posts in that category. How I can retrieve this label name?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var homepage = "http://MYBLOG.blogspot.com";
function recentpostslist(json) {
document.write('<select style="width:100%;"     onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">');
var label = "Select a Post";
var ddTitle = "<option>"+label+"</option>";
document.write(ddTitle);
for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++)
{   
    for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
        if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
            break;
        }
    }       
    var entryUrl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
    var entryTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
    var item = "<option style='width:210px;' value=" + entryUrl + '>' + entryTitle; 
    document.write(item);
    document.write('</option>');
}
document.write('</select>');
}
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + homepage + '/feeds/posts/summary/-/Appetizers?max-results=10&alt=json-in-script&callback=recentpostslist"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```